# How to upload ignored vendor folder to Git?

Tags: php, html, git, laravel, bitbucket

I am using lavalite(Laravel) as the CMS. I updated the home.blade.php to change the layout and wordings of texts. Home.blade.php is located in /resources/views/vendor/user/public/admin/home.blade.php

After updating this file, it is not detected by Git and I cannot upload it to a remote repository.

How to disable ignored folder?

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to modify `.gitignore` or other ignore things, you can simply run `git add -f -- <path>` to add the ignored path by force. `git status --ignored` can list the ignored files.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should do is check [`.gitingore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) file for `resources/views/vendor` folder.

Or if you have `vendor/` line in `.gitignore` you can try to delete it, but keep `/vendor` line (with `/` in the beginnig).

Answer (score 1):

Go to folder project and search .gitignore file.
Open .gitingore and delete the path of folder.